# When does a problem constitute a code review?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, code-review-se

I am wondering if my question about [Clojure sequences](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23547/is-there-a-better-way-to-extract-a-single-value-instead-of-a-sequence) could be considered an SO question instead, or if this is more a CodeReview question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The distinction between Code Review and Stack Overflow is quite clear:

- You have working code and you want to improve it? Use Codereview.
- You have broken code and wonder how to fix it? Use Stack Overflow.

Your question is a fine fit for Code Review, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. My code is not broken; I just wanted to improve it.